# I want to save both image and string data on the server by using retrofit multipart but I am getting an error

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to save both image and string data on the server by using retrofit multipart but I am getting an error "500 Internal Server Error"
here's https://prnt.sc/p95pe7

The API is running fine on Postman but there is an error in retrofit

```
  @Multipart
  @POST("item_app")
  Call<ItemAddResponse> addNewItem(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                 @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                 @Part("description") RequestBody description,
                                 @Part("tags") RequestBody tags,
                                 @Part("category") RequestBody category,
                                 @Part("stock_status") RequestBody stock_status,
                                 @Part("sku") RequestBody sku,
                                 @Part("quantity") RequestBody quantity,
                                 @Part("pcs_per_box") RequestBody pcs_per_box,
                                 @Part("price") RequestBody price,
                                 @Part("safe_quantity") RequestBody safe_quantity,
                                 @Part("remarks") RequestBody remarks
                                 );
```

And I am using it like this

```
  Call<ItemAddResponse> call = NetworkConfig.getApiService().addNewItem(
                NetworkConfig.createFilePartFromFile("profile_img", finalImagePath),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(name),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(description),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(tags),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(category),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(stockStatus),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(sku),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(quantity),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(pcsPerBox),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(price),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(safeQuantity),
                NetworkConfig.createPartFromString(remarks)
                );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemAddResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ItemAddResponse> call, Response<ItemAddResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   Utility.getInstance().hideProgressDialog();

                    ItemAddResponse itemAddResponse = null;
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        itemAddResponse = response.body();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response addNewItemService : " + itemAddResponse);

                    if ( itemAddResponse.getStatus() == 200 ) {
                        ItemAddDialog itemAddDialog = ItemAddDialog.newInstance();
                        ((ItemAddDialog) itemAddDialog).setCallback(new ItemAddDialog.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onActionClick() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        itemAddDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
                    }

                } else {
                    Utility.getInstance().hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ItemAddResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Utility.getInstance().hideProgressDialog();
                Utility.dialogError(AddNewItemActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
```

Where I am using this function for add string

```
@NonNull
public static RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    if (descriptionString == null)
        return null;

    return RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
}
```

and this function use for adding file

```
@NonNull
public static MultipartBody.Part createFilePartFromFile(String partName, String file_path) {
    MultipartBody.Part body = null;
    if (file_path != null) {
        File file = new File(file_path);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
        return body;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is correct, there might be a problem with the method you're using to create file part, try this out :

```
    pictureBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("yourTag", 
      selectedFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), 
      selectedFile));
```

Please note, I am sending file, not file path.

Comment: Did you try hitting API using postman to make sure its working fine?